# HikariCP not releasing active MySql connections

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp, spring-repositories

I have recently updated from JDK 8 to JDK 11 (issue not exists in JDK 8) and in the process updated the app Hikari dependency to 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:3.3.1' and I am using springBootVersion = '2.1.3.RELEASE'.  The app has 2 data sources, 1 postgres and 1 MySql.  Postgres is fine but MySql is not.  As the Pool expires connections and adds new connections the active connections are created and never released, from the hikari perspective.  When querying the DB it only shows the 5 idle connections that I expect to see.  This continues until I reach the max pool size and then the app starts to sporadically fail to connect.
Has anyone seen anything like this and/or does anyone know something that could help me get to the bottom of this?

The limited logs I could get for this issue:

```
mysql-17 - After cleanup stats (total=12, active=7, idle=5, waiting=0)
mysql-17 - Before cleanup stats (total=12, active=7, idle=5, waiting=0)
at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:562)
... 89 more
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1186)
at batch.processor.Processor.processRequest(Processor.java:50)
at batch.processor.Processor.checkinStaleAssignedTransaction(Processor.java:76)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:275)
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
mysql-17 - After cleanup stats (total=11, active=6, idle=5, waiting=0)
mysql-17 - Before cleanup stats (total=11, active=6, idle=5, waiting=0)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
STACKTRACE:
MESSAGE: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
javax.net.ssl.SSLException
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:
Thu Jul 25 14:52:55 UTC 2019 WARN: Caught while disconnecting...
mysql-17 - Closing connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@79447870: (
```

The MySql Config is:

```
# MySql Properties
mysql.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
mysql.datasource.jdbcUrl=${DB_URL}
mysql.datasource.username=${SECRET_DB_USERNAME}
mysql.datasource.password=${SECRET_DB_PASSWORD}
mysql.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

mysql.datasource.connection-timeout=7000
mysql.datasource.maximum-pool-size=30
mysql.datasource.minimum-idle=5
mysql.datasource.idle-timeout=300000
mysql.datasource.max-lifetime=600000
mysql.datasource.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
mysql.datasource.leak-detection-threshold=3000
mysql.datasource.pool-name=mysql-${node.id}

mysql.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

The MySql Spring Java config is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "mySqlEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "mySqlTransactionManager", basePackages = {"mysql.dao", "models"})
public class MySqlConfiguration {
    @Value("${mysql.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect}")
    private String dialect;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mySqlTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager mySqlTransactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(mySqlEntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = {
        "entityManagerFactory", "mySqlEntityManagerFactory"
    })
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mySqlEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("hibernate.dialect", dialect);

        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("mysql");
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(props);
        factoryBean.setDataSource(mysqlDataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("models", "mysql.entity");

        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "mysqlDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mysql.datasource")
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }
}
```

**** EDIT ****
Some additional logging that may help:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 417 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 417 milliseconds ago.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.getProduct(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doDataSourceHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(DataSourceHealthIndicator.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator.health(CompositeHealthIndicator.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointWebExtension.health(HealthEndpointWebExtension.java:54)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor206.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$ServletWebOperationAdapter.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:294)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping.java:355)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor205.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:867)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at tracing.shadow.io.opentracing.contrib.web.servlet.filter.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 417 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 417 milliseconds ago.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1218)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getUserName(DatabaseMetaData.java:4036)
    at tracing.shadow.io.opentracing.contrib.spring.cloud.jdbc.JdbcAspect.getConnection(JdbcAspect.java:44)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor201.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8dfc4e21.getConnection(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:157)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78)
    ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 417 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 417 milliseconds ago.
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor201.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:562)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:732)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:671)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:986)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryString(NativeProtocol.java:921)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:1154)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1186)
    ... 99 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.FullReadInputStream.readFully(FullReadInputStream.java:67)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketReader.readHeader(SimplePacketReader.java:45)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:52)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketReader.readHeader(TimeTrackingPacketReader.java:41)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:54)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.MultiPacketReader.readHeader(MultiPacketReader.java:44)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readMessage(NativeProtocol.java:556)
    ... 105 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Just to add to this, I reverted the JDK version back to 8 and left everything else the same and the connection leak stopped.  So I am guessing it is an issue with how Spring is is handling the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html) isn't supporting Java 11, only up to 8

> Connector/J 8.0 is a Type 4 pure Java JDBC 4.2 driver for the Java 8 platform.
>
> JRE Supported  1.8.x

There was a [question](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,670423,670493#msg-670493) in MySQL forum answered simply to report a bug (which I didn't find any)

> We don't have any plans to do so at the moment.
>
> I would suggest you to file a feature request in https://bugs.mysql.com/report.php providing all details you can so that we can start analyzing it.